# SSIS Google Analytics - Reporting dimensions & metrics are incompatible

Tags: visual-studio, google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to extract data from Google Analytics, using KingswaySoft - SSIS Integration Toolkit, in Visual Studio.

[image: SSIS Dataflow:]

I've set the metrics and dimensions, but I get this error message:

*Please remove transactions to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/*

I've tried to remove transactions metric and it works, but this metric is really necessary.

- **Metrics**: sessionConversionRate, sessions, totalUsers, transactions
- **Dimensions**: campaignName, country, dateHour, deviceCategory, sourceMedium

[image: Google Analytics Source Editor (Connector from KingswaySoft - SSIS Integration Toolkit)]

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how helpful this suggestion is but could a possible work around include having two queries.

Query 1: Existing query without transactions 
Query 2: The same dimensions with transactionId included

The idea would be to use the SSIS Aggregate component to group by the original dimensions and count the transactions. You could then merge the queries together via a merge join.

Would that work?

Comment: I tried to create two different data flow tasks: On the 1st it extracts all the dimensions and only the metric "transactions". On the 2nd it extracts all the dimensions plus all the remaining metrics that I need, but it still retrieves an error when I try to extract transactions. 

I've checked and the dimensions that are not compatible with the metric "transactions" are the "campaignName" and "sourceMedium". How should I proceed in this query where I'm trying to extract only the transactions metric?

Comment: Hello, 
The idea was to have query 1 as your current query but remove transactions. Then for query two, you only have the same dimensions but include the transactionId dimension. For the second query, you perform an aggregation in SSIS, grouping by the dimensions (campaignName,Country,dateHour,deviceCategory,sourceMedium). 

It's basically performing a transaction count 'manually' grouped by those dimensions. You could then potentially join the queries together.

Answer (score 1):

The API supports what it supports. So if you've attempted to pair things that are incompatible, you won't get any data back. Things that seem like they should totally work go together like orange juice and milk.

While I worked on the GA stuff through Python, an approach we found helped us work through incompatible metrics and total metrics was to make multiple pulls using the same dimensions. As the data sets are at the same level of grain, as long as you match up each dimension in the set, you can have all the metrics you want.

In your case, I'd have 2 data flows, followed by an Execute SQL Task that brings the data together for the final table

- DFT1: Query1 -> Derived Column -> Stage.Table1
- DFT2: Query2 -> Derived Column -> Stage.Table2

### Execute SQL Task

```
SELECT
    T1.*, T2.Metric_A, T2.Metric_B, ... T2.Metric_Z
INTO
    #T
FROM
    Stage.T1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN
        Stage.T2 AS T2
        ON T2.Dim1 = T1.Dim1 /* etc */ AND T2.Dim7 = T1.Dim7

-- Update you have solid data aka 
-- isDataGolden exists in the "data" section of the response
-- Usually within 7? days but possibly sooner
UPDATE
    X
SET
    metric1 = S.metric1 /* etc */
FROM
    dbo.X AS X
    INNER JOIN #T AS T
    ON T.Dim1 = X.Dim1 
WHERE
    X.isDataGolden IS NULL
    AND T.isDataGolden IS NOT NULL;

-- Add new data but be aware that not all nodes might have 
-- reported in.        
INSERT INTO
    dbo.X
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #T AS T
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.X AS X WHERE X.Dim1 = T.Dim1 /* etc */);
```

Comment: I tried to create two different data flow tasks:

On the 1st it extracts all the dimensions and only the metric "transactions". On the 2nd it extracts all the dimensions plus all the remaining metrics that I need, but it still retrieves an error when I try to extract transactions.

Comment: Interesting. I can't use the dimensions/metrics explorer link as I no longer have access to that client's keys but this sounds like transactions is incompatible with campaignName, country, dateHour, deviceCategory, or sourceMedium (or a combination of them). If that's the case, then you simply can't build what is being asked of you.

Comment: The other thing that bit us was we pulled data at the daily level for a variety of metrics and dimensions. In April, we pulled the previous 4 years. In May, we realized we needed to re-pull the analytics and previously working api queries bombed out as the user* flavored dimensions were flagged as they were potentially unmasking visitors. My note says "ga:userAgeBracket & ga:userGender became incompatible with source/referrer/keyword"